# meaning of 都 in 从小就好爱看国外都明星街拍！

Tags: meaning, sentence

I found a sentence in an article that says,
"不知道大家是不是和我一样，从小就好爱看国外都明星街拍！"

I understand all the meaning of the sentence but can't understand what part 都 plays in the sentence. Any help will be useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably a typo for 的

Answer (score 2):

都 is in wrong position in your sentence.

"不知道大家是不是**都**和我一样，从小就好爱看国外明星街拍！" is correct.

or

"不知道大家是不是和我一样，从小就好爱看国外(的)明星街拍！" is also correct.

国外都明星街拍 doesn't make sense.